# Fetching data from MongoDB for two different reasons

Tags: mongodb, api, mean-stack

I am developing a project on MEAN stack in visual studio code. I have a component which having search box for one field and as well as search box for another field.
First I want to search for one field i.e.,Mobile number. The data which is relevant to particular mobile number has been displaying. Here my requirement is when I am searching for another field i.e., date, the data which is relevant to particular date has to display.

Finally I am asking that how can I send two requests from same component? How can I write POST requests for those two Queries from same component? What is the approach? I am done with single query i.e., Mobile number its working.

```
 //this is my API

app.post('/security',(req,res)=>{
    // var resultArray=[];
    var url="mongodb://localhost:27017/gateway";
    mongo.connect(url,(err,db)=>{
        var dbo=db.db("gateway");
        dbo.collection("vstrinfo").find({"dov":{$gte:("2017-04- 
       14T23:59:59Z"),$lte:("2017-04-15T23:59:59Z")}}).toArray((err,data)=>{

            console.log(data);
            if(err) throw err;
            res.send(data);
            res.end();
            })
            dbo.collection("vstrinfo").find({"mobile":req.body.search})
                .toArray((err,data)=>{
            console.log(data);
            if(err) throw err;
            res.send(data);
            res.end();

        })
    })
})
```

This is my component view

[image]